# jdbc performance

Tags: java, jdbc

There are thee tables inside my database.  One is `employee`, the second is `employee_Project`, and the third is `employee_Reporting`.  Each table has a common `employee_Number` as its primary key, and there is a one to many relationship among them such that an employee has many projects and reporting dates.

I have run `select * from employee`, `select * from employee_project`, `select * from employee_reporting` in three data holder classes which have methods `fillResultSet(Result set)` and `List<T> getData()`. This is based on a `SqlDbEngine` class with a  `runQuery(PreparedStatement,DataHolder)` method, and the implementation has been completed.

Now I have to design a `getAllEmployee()` method along with project and reporting detail with optimal code in java using JDBC.  I have used an iterator but this solution is not acceptable; now I have to use a foreach loop.

This is what I have done:

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    EmployeeDataHolderImpl empdataholder = new EmployeeDataHolderImpl();
    List<Employee> list_Employee_Add = null;

    try {
        Connection connection = mySqlDbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement(GET_ALL_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS);
        mySqlDBEngineImpl.runQuery(preparedStatement, empdataholder);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Employee employee : empdataholder.getData()) {
        new EmployeeDAOImpl().getProject(employee);
                    new EmployeeDAOImpl.getReport(employee);
    }
    list_Employee_Add = empdataholder.getData();
    return list_Employee_Add;

}
```

and make another method

```
    public void getProject(Employee emp) {
    EmployeeProjectDataHolderImpl employeeProjectHolder = new EmployeeProjectDataHolderImpl();
    try {
        Connection connection = mySqlDbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement(GET_ALL_PROJECT_DETAILS);
        mySqlDBEngineImpl
                .runQuery(preparedStatement, employeeProjectHolder);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (EmployeeProject employee_Project : employeeProjectHolder.getData()) {
        if (employee_Project.getEmployeeNumber() == emp.getEmpNumber()) {
            emp.getProjects().add(employee_Project);
        }
    }
}

    public void getReport(Employee emp) {
    EmployeeReportDataHolderImpl employeeReportHolder = new EmployeeReportDataHolderImpl();
    try {
        Connection connection = mySqlDbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement(GET_ALL_REPORT_DETAILS);
        mySqlDBEngineImpl
                .runQuery(preparedStatement, employeeReportHolder);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (EmployeeReport employee_Report : employeeReportHolder.getData()) {
        if (employee_Report.getEmployeeNumber() == emp.getEmpNumber()) {
            emp.getProjects().add(employee_Project);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and same for Employee Reporting but doing, this performance is going to decrease.no body worry about closing connection i will do it

Please tell me how I could improve my solution..

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  You say that you've already done an implementation of `select * from employee`.  Isn't this basically going to be your `getAllEmployees()` method?  Also, you mention that your iterator-based solution is not acceptable, so you need to use a foreach loop.  Foreach **is** an iterator - it's just syntactic sugar!  What's the *real* reason why you need to use foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your actual code, you will have 3 impacts in your code:

- You're opening a connection to get the employee's data.
- For every employee, you open (and close) a new connection to get his projects.
- For every employee, you open (and close) a new connection to get his reports.

Note that opening a new connection is a performance hit on your application. It doesn't matter if you use an enhanced for-loop or an Iterator, there would be many hits that can slow down your application.

Two ways to solve this problem:

1. Open a single connection where you run all your select statements. This will be better than opening/closing lot of connections.
2. Create a single SQL statement to retrieve the employees and the data you need for every employee. It will have better performance for different reasons:

   - A single connection to the database.
   - A single query instead of lot of queries to the database (a single I/O operation).
   - If your rdbms allows it, the query will be optimized for future requests (a single query instead of multiple queries).

I would prefer to go with the second option. For this, I tend to use a method that executes any SQL select statement and return a ResultSet. I'll post a basic example (note, the provided code can be improved depending on your needs), this method could be in your `SqlDbEngine` class:

```
public ResultSet executeSQL(Connection con, String sql, List<Object> arguments) {
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (arguments != null) {
            int i = 1;
            for(Object o : arguments) {
                pstmt.setObject(i++, o);
            }
        }
        //method to execute insert, update, delete statements...
        rs = pstmt.execute();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        //handle the error...
    }
    return rs;
}
```

And this other method to handle all the query operation

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<Employee> lstEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    try {
        con = mySqlDbConnection.getConnection();
        //write the sql to retrieve all the data
        //I'm assuming these can be your columns, it's up to you
        //this can be written using JOINs...
        String sql = "SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.EMPLOYEE_NAME, P.PROJECT_NAME, R.REPORT_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE E, PROJECT P, REPORT R WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID = P.EMPLOYEE_ID AND E.EMPLOYEE_ID = R.EMPLOYEE_ID";
        //I guess you don't need parameters for this...
        rs = SqlDbEngine.executeSQL(con, sql, null);
        if (rs != null) {
            Employee e;
            int employeeId = -1, lastEmployeeId = -1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                //you need to make sure to create a new employee only when
                //reading a new employee id
                employeeId = rs.getInt("EMPLOYEE_ID");
                if (lastEmployeeId != employeeId) {
                    e = new Employee();
                    lastEmployeeId = employeeId;
                    lstEmployee.add(e);
                }
                Project p = new Project();
                Report r = new Report();
                //fill values of p...
                //fill values of r...
                //you can fill the values taking advantage of the column name in the resultset
                //at last, link the project and report to the employee
                e.getProjects().add(p);
                e.getReports().add(r);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle the error...
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                Statement stmt = rs.getStatement();
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //handle the error...
        }
    }
    return lstEmployee;
}
```

Note that the second way can be harder to code but it will give you the best performance. It's up to you to improve the provided methods, some advices:

- Create a class that receives a ResultSet and builds a `Project` instance using the columns name of the ResultSet (similar for `Report` and `Employee`).
- Create a method that handles the `ResultSet` and its `Statement` close.
- As a best practice, **never** use `select * from mytable`, it's preferable to write the needed columns.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issue with your code.

1.you are initializing EmployeeDAOImpl everytime, rather you can just keep one instance and call the operations over it.

> new EmployeeDAOImpl().getProject(employee);   new
>   EmployeeDAOImpl.getReport(employee);

2.I don't see where you close your connection after performing an SQL operation.

Comment: Even with this, there's a big performance hit when opening connections to retrieve all the projects and just get the projects he/she needs to bind to the employee (and similar for reports). The code will be heavily improved by using a single connection that retrieves all the values joined and ordered as OP wants/needs.

Comment: @Arham all the connection are closed in sqldbEngine class i dont have to worry about i have just only design the method getAllEmployee() where i have comparing each employee object attribute employee_Number to each object of Employeereporting and EmployeeProject class suppose for one Employee there is 4 project and there is lakhs of data present in databse thn my logic gonna be burst cause for each object i m comparing just each and every object attribute Employee_no of project and reporting class iteratively using for each loop and also i dont have to use join

Comment: @ankurjadiya by doing that you're recovering like 100 elements when you just need 4. And you will do the same **for every employee**. If you want to enhance your performance, you should learn and apply best practices.

Answer (score 1):

You should be having

```
try {

--code statements 

}
catch(SQLException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
-- close your connection and preparedStatement
}
```

Closing database connections is very vital.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your code first loads all `EmployeeReport` rows and then filters them according to `getEmployeeNumber()`. You can let your database do this by modifying your SQL query.

Since you didn't show your SQL queries (I assume they're in `GET_ALL_REPORT_DETAILS`), I'll just make a guess... Try executing SQL like:

```
select *
from employee_reporting
where employeeNumber = ?
```

If you put this in a `PreparedStatement`, and then set the parameter value, your database will only return the data you need. For example:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(GET_ALL_REPORT_DETAILS);
pstmt.setInt(1, employee.getEmployeeNumber());
```

That should return only the `EmployeeReport` records having the desired `employeeNumber`. In case performance is still an issue, you could consider adding an index to your `EmployeeReport` table, but that's a different story...

Comment: no sir i just declared like this String GET_ALL_REPORT_DETAILS="select * from Employee" actually i have used all column name in place  of * same is done for all constant

Comment: That shouldn't really make a big difference. `*` is just a shortcut for "all columns in all tables that are listed in the `FROM`-clause".